# Concentration of acid when titration has reached equivalence point?

Tags: acid-base, concentration, titration

I'm currently working with a lab report concerning titration. One of the tasks is to calculate the concentration of the weak acid ($\ce{HOAc}$) and the strong acid ($\ce{HCl}$) at the equivalence point during titration (through $\ce{NaOH}$).

But shouldn't the concentration of $\ce{HOAc}$ and $\ce{HCl}$ in the new solutions per definition be 0. Hasn't all acid at that point been neutralized and converted to its conjugate base at the equivalence point?